# Why can't the "whenever" gem find the "bash" command?

Tags: ruby, rvm, whenever

I am using the "[whenever](http://rubygems.org/gems/whenever)" Ruby gem and [RVM](http://rvm.io/) to control my rubies/gemsets. When I try using whenever, I see the following error.

```
/bin/bash: not found
```

Comment: The version of RVM, Ruby, and the gem itself usually help when answering these questions. I see you have a good answer this time, though. Hope this helps in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Appears the whenever gem has /bin/bash  hardcoded

`set :job_template, "/bin/bash -l -c ':job'"`

Not all OS put bash in the same place.

It would appear that you are using an operating system where bash is not in /bin  (probably in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin)

You will need to update the job_template to match the location of bash  or you could do

`set :job_template, "bash -l -c ':job'"`

To let the shell locate the correct version of bash for you.